# How to replace "#" with 1's in python?

Tags: python, numpy

If have an array of elements in the following format seen below, how can i swap #'s or .'s for 1's?
I have tried this code but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

```
lines = ['..##...', '...#...', '...#...', '..#.#..']

for line in lines:

for i in line:
    if(i == "#"):
        i = 1
    else:
        i = -1
print(lines)
```

Comment: You can just do this: `if i == '#:'` no need for those parantheses

Comment: Assigning to `i` within the loop doesn't change the original string.

Comment: Must `lines` be altered in place or is the goal only to change what is printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
lines = ['..##...', '...#...', '...#...', '..#.#..']
newLines = []
for i in lines:
    newLines.append(i.replace('#',"1"))
print(newLines)
```

If you would like to replace it with "."

```
lines = ['..##...', '...#...', '...#...', '..#.#..']
newLines = []
for i in lines:
    newLines.append(i.replace('#',"."))
print(newLines)
```

Comment: this works well thanks, but i need an if statement to change the "."s as well. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why you would need and if statement.

Comment: nevermind! it worked perfectly when i added another replace: newLines.append(i.replace('#',"1").replace('.', "-1"))

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use `replace` to replace `#` with `1`. Also make sure to use `'1'`, because `1` is not a string representation but an integer.
This can be done with list comprehension:

```
[i.replace('#', '1') for i in lines]
```

Result:

```
['..11...', '...1...', '...1...', '..1.1..']
```